# How to var_dump data in the file controller and Model

Tags: magento-1.9, debugging, debug

How do I `var_dump` data in the file controller and Model?

I tried: `var_dump` and `die`

and view source ... but it's not displayed

Answer (score 4):

I rarely use var_dump or echo to the screen when programming Magento. I find it far better to use print_r in conjunction with the Magento logging function.

Add a line like this to your code -

```
Mage::log("this is my data -\n".print_r($model->debug(),true),1,"mylogfile.log",true);
```

This will dump the debug data for the model to a log file called mylogfile.log in the var/log directory under Magento's root.  The final true parameter to the log function forced the logger to write regardless of Magento's logging setting.